# Custom InboundEmail handler - check if message is an automatic reply

Tags: apex, email, apex-email-service, email2case

I've implemented a custom inbound email handler for some departments using email-to-case, and we would need to avoid autoreply messages or automatic generated messages to create cases or trigger other actions in the handler.

I've seen there is an RFC which explains how to check in the inbound email headers if that message is an automatic-generated one (see http://www.iana.org/assignments/auto-submitted-keywords/auto-submitted-keywords.xhtml) but I'm afraid that salesforce does not support that specific RFC (salesforce headers support RFC 2822 as explained here http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_inbound_email.htm&language=en_US)

Just as workaround we check that email subject does not contain typical out of the office or autoreply words, but i don't think this is a real solution.

Does anyone know any other way of cheking if the message is an automatic-generated one in salesforce?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Einstein can be used to do this using a feature called email insights. It can do the following:

- Capture 'Out of Office' by default
- Capture custom insights via keywords
- Filter email to only show those with insights

**References**

- [Create Custom Einstein Email Insights](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=aac_custom_email_insights.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null)
- [Predict Priorities with Einstein Email Insights](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_sales_inbox_einstein_email_insights.htm)